# Mouse-click without moving cursor in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, click, headless

Is it possible to click on coordinates in headless mode?
Something like this command:

```
pg.click(3891, 271)
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you want to `click` using `X,Y coordinate` you can do like below:*

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

***import***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Make sure the browser window is maximized `driver.maximize_window()`

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution to this myself, try

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

I needed this to click an element that was behind a banner ad. so this clicks the element directly through Javascript

Comment: But can I use this with X,Y coordinates?

Comment: you could find the element by location and pass it in as the second argument "element"