# Python Selenium x and y offset of element to click on

Tags: python, selenium, mouse-position

in Selenium with Python I want to mouse-navigate to elements by coordinates and to click etc. - because that xpath-way and others doesn't work.

I saw that there is an action "move_by_offset" for it.

Where do I could read out the X and Y position of an exist element?

I tried this for exampel:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.de")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
##Cookieaccept
search1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "L2AGLb")
search1.click()

##google logo
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lnXdpd")
```

Is there a function?
Because

```
loc = element.location
print (loc)
```

Gives X and Y output

Gives my an output of x and y but I need both in separte integers to use move_by_offset()

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(X,Y)
```

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567161/11863448 answer your question?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, this answer not my question because 
action.move_by_offset(x_coordinate, y_coordinate) I have already.
The question is how can i extract X and Y of (for example:) loc = element.location  separate in this two X and Y variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `element.location` return a dict with x and y coordinates, use
`dictionary.get()` method

```
loc = element.location
X, Y = loc.get('x'), loc.get('y')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(X,Y)
```

Otherwise you can use `ActionChain.move_to_element()` method

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lnXdpd")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```